# How can I summarise Meteorological data grouped by day (e.g. daily mean temperature)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a simple data frame. I want to summarise temperature data to find daily means.
But I'm having trouble grouping data by days (or date).
Here is my dataframe:

```
head(met_df)
    longdate     time     temp       ru
1 2022-01-17 19:35:16 26.45090 51.07734
2 2022-01-17 19:40:16 26.32881 52.05396
3 2022-01-17 19:45:16 26.10930 53.44564
4 2022-01-17 19:50:16 26.01184 53.39681
5 2022-01-17 19:55:16 25.79276 54.37344
6 2022-01-17 20:00:16 25.64688 54.81292
```

I tried

```
met_df %>%
  group_by(longdate) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(temp))
```

found the overall mean temperature.

and also tried

```
summarise(met_df, 
          group_by(longdate),
          meantemp = mean(temp))
```

to

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

What am I doing wrong?

df is

```
    > dput(met_df[50:60,])
structure(list(longdate = c("2022-01-17", "2022-01-17", "2022-01-17", 
"2022-01-17", "2022-01-18", "2022-01-18", "2022-01-18", "2022-01-18", 
"2022-01-18", "2022-01-18", "2022-01-18"), time = c("23:40:16", 
"23:45:16", "23:50:16", "23:55:16", "00:00:16", "00:05:16", "00:10:16", 
"00:15:16", "00:20:16", "00:25:16", "00:30:16"), temp = c(21.6044187155778, 
21.7954899898467, 21.7477126301733, 21.5805418389905, 21.4850494528608, 
21.2464202287555, 21.0556153153795, 20.9364037750932, 20.8410563512717, 
20.8887276946045, 20.8410563512717), ru = c(72.0258804858695, 
71.0248428248795, 70.878349508637, 71.7573094060917, 72.1479582494049, 
73.3443203320515, 74.4674357565769, 76.2009399987792, 75.7858756027589, 
75.5661356283953, 76.3718488677287)), row.names = 50:60, class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `dplyr::group_by(longdate)`

Comment: Your full dataframe has more than one unique `longdate`, right? Your first codeblock does look correct — one reason for returning the “overall” mean would be if there’s only one group.

Comment: Would you please give a reproducible data frame?

Comment: I do have more than one group in long date
>levels(as.factor(met_df$longdate))
 [1] "2022-01-17" "2022-01-18" "2022-01-19" "2022-01-20" "2022-01-21" "2022-01-22" "2022-01-23" "2022-01-24"
 [9] "2022-01-25" "2022-01-26" "2022-01-27" "2022-01-28" "2022-01-29" "2022-01-30" "2022-01-31" "2022-02-01"
[17] "2022-02-02" "2022-02-03" "2022-02-04" "2022-02-05" "2022-02-06" "2022-02-07" "2022-02-08"

Comment: the problem persist with dplyr::group_by

Comment: Please post `dput(met_df)`

Comment: dput was added in the question

Comment: Your code totally works for me.  I get a data frame with two rows, one for each date.  There are two columns: `longdate` and `mean`.  Try restarting your R session

Answer (score 1):

When working with dates, I would recommend you work with `lubridate` package. For example, working with `nycflight` sample dataset you can group with the function `month()` or whatever aggregation you want like this:

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

data = flights

data %>%
  mutate(month_agg = month(time_hour)) %>%
  group_by(month_agg) %>%
  summarize(mean_air = mean(air_time,na.rm = T))
```

Seems that there might be some problem when grouping by your column because of the format. Insuring it with `lubricate` can be a good approach I think.